# Cannot open some files when stored in a "cloud" location (iCloud/One/Google Drive, etc.)

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, google-apps, onedrive

I'm using the officials OneDrive (version `23.071.0402.0001`) and Google Drive (version `73.0.4.0`) macOS apps to sync my cloud files on my Mac. It worked fine for few months, but now I cannot open some files (either Google Drive or One Drive), mostly `.docx` and `.pdf` ones but not limited to them.

The files are synced to be replicated locally so they are present on the hard drive and they are usable offline. For instance, I'm able to copy a file to the Downloads folder and open it while being offline, but I cannot open it directly from the cloud drive folder.

This does not seem to be related to the app used to load the file, the app works fine in other situations. Moreover, I'm unable to open such files with **any** app (for instances Pages for a `.docx` file). I also checked the privileges of the files and folder and they are normal. What is weird is that I'm able to preview those files with QuickLook (still being offline) but not open them. The app launches but the files never open.

I restarted the Mac and the OneDrive and Google apps and switch off then on the sync process but this did not solve the issue. My Mac is up to date, though, it's the last compatible version (macOs Monterey 12.6.4) since it's a MacBook Air early 2015 which is not updatable anymore. I tried to reinstall completely Google Drive and download again all files and the issue is still here.

The issue seems to disappear if I disable the local replication of the files (at least in Google Drive), but this defeat the purpose of local replication and its not an option since I need my files offline. For OneDrive the issue disappear if I duplicate the file, but this is not practical neither. I tried to move the un-openable files to iCloud and I get the same issue, I cannot open them. it only works if the files **are not** in a "Cloud" location, i.e. local only.

**I was able to replicate the issue on a different machine (MacBook Pro 14" M1 Pro running macOS Ventura) with a different Google account, thus, I strongly believe that the issue is with the File Provider API rather than the files or account.**

Comment: What are the versions of the apps that you try use to edit .docx files? What are the version of Google Drive and OneDrive installable clients? How much free space that your Mac? What type of Internet connection are you using?

Comment: @Rubén I updated the post with the OneDrive and Google Drive versions. The Mac free space is greater than 300GB. The internet connection is working and the issue arises on all the networks I tried, thus I think that the network type is not relevant. As stated in the post, the issue is not tied to `.docx` files only nor to a specific app for opening.

Comment: Thanks Louis. I have a MacMini, M1, Ventura, with the same version of the Drive client. I very rarely work with .docx files, but I do frequently with .xlsx and other formats. I can't reproduce the problem. P.S. Avoid meta-tags (EDIT, EDIT 2, EDIT 3...) as posts have a revision history. You might use the Edit summary field to describe the change. Instead organize the content in such way that the post is easier to read for new readers.

Comment: I edited the post to avoid the meta-tags, thanks. I updated to the last macOS version (12.6.5 released on April 10) and this did not solve the issue. Next step will be to reinstall macOS from scratch.

Comment: I did a clean install (erased SSD, reinstalled macOS, NVRAM reseted, etc.), updated the OS, reinstalled the apps and put back the data from scratch (no migration assistant nor Time Machine backup) and the issue is still present. It's probably a macOS issue, thus I'll report it to Apple directly.